# How to Pass Column Values to DBT Macro When Column Names Have '.' Characters

Tags: postgresql, jinja2, dbt

I have a simple macro

```
{% macro parse_url_string_format(input_value) %}
  {% if 'utm' in input_value %}
    {{ input_value }}
  {% else %}
    ''
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I want to use it in the following way:

```
select {{parse_url_string_format(col_a)}} as parsed_a
from table_1
```

Okay, that works fine. However, the name of my column is actually `my.column.a`... it has a bunch of `.` characters in it. No worries; the usual way to handle this in a `select` statement is merely to surround the column name with `"` characters. But, when I do that:

```
select {{parse_url_string_format(my.column.a)}} as parsed_a
from table_1
```

Then dbt actually sends the string `'my.column.a` into the macro, and not the *value* of the column. What is the syntax to send the value of the column?

Comment: Have you tried single quotes, double quotes or both, double-in-single? The [doc example](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/jinja-macros#macros) sounds like you're supposed to single-quote the column name in macro call, unless `col_a` is actually a variable. `select {{parse_url_string_format('my.column.a')}} as parsed_a
from table_1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are in a pg-compatible dialect, and use double quotes for identifiers, e.g., `"my.column.a"`...

You can either nest quotes in the call to the macro:

```sql
select {{parse_url_string_format('"my.column.a"')}} as parsed_a
```

or you can rewrite the macro to quote the identifier:

```sql
{% macro parse_url_string_format(input_value) %}
  {% if 'utm' in input_value %}
    "{{ input_value }}"
  {% else %}
    ''
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Keep in mind that the DATA from your database does NOT pass through your macro; in this case the `input_value` for your macro is a string that represents the name of a column; accordingly, when you write `{% if 'utm' in input_value %}`, you mean "if 'utm' is in the NAME OF THE COLUMN stored in the variable input_value", not "if 'utm' is in data stored in the column named input_value".

For MySQL or BQ, just replace the double quotes above with backicks (`` ` ``).

Comment: Thanks! I had a wrong mental model of macros! They all just get templated back to sql code.